# Hardened Scales + Champion of Lambholt + Token Generator

Tags: magic-the-gathering

- [Champion of Lambholt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChampion%20of%20Lambholt%5d): Gets a +1/+1 counter whenever a creature enters the battlefield.
- [Hardened Scales](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHardened%20Scales%5d): Whenever 1 or more counters are put on a creature, put one more of those counters on that creature.
- [Gather the Townsfolk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGather%20the%20Townsfolk%5d): Put two 1/1 human tokens on the battlefield.

If I play Gather the Townsfolk, does Champion get 3 counters or 4?

Comment: "Whenever" indicates a triggered ability, but HS has a static ability that creates a continuous effect that's a replacement effect. Avoid using "when" or "whenever" for these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Four.

When the two tokens enter the battlefield, [Champion of Lambholt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChampion%20of%20Lambholt%5d)'s triggered ability triggers twice. It will be placed on the stack twice. When the topmost instance resolves, it would add a +1/+1 counter to Champion of Lambholt. Instead, it adds one extra, so two. When the other instance resolves, it will also add two, so a total of 4 +1/+1 counters are added to Champion of Lambholt.

Comment: Is this an issue of timing  (one token gets summoned, then another, in near instant time), or are the tokens spawning simultaneously but each token is a valid trigger for Champion (causing each trigger to be an isolated incident, and both valid for Scales)?

Comment: It depends on the wording of the trigger condition. If it says "Whenever one or more creature enters the battlefield", then the ability would only trigger once when GotT resolves. But here we have the far more common "Whenever a creature enters the battlefield". It doesn't matter if it enters at the same time as another creature. *603.2c An ability triggers only once each time its trigger event occurs. However, it can trigger repeatedly if one event contains multiple occurrences*